Loop over execute immediate
I want to loop over a dynamic query that was concatenated before. However, even with this simple example
begin
  for rec in (execute immediate 'select dummy from dual') loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.dummy);
  end loop;
end;

I get the error

encountered the symbol immediate when expecting one of the following

How to achieve such a loop?

You can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and BULK COLLECT the results into a collection variable and then loop through that:
DECLARE
  TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1);
  v_strings string_list;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select dummy from dual'
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_strings;

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_strings.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_strings(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
X


If you have multiple columns you can use:
DECLARE
  TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1);
  v_numbers number_list;
  v_strings string_list;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select dummy, level from dual connect by level <= 5'
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_strings, v_numbers;

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_strings.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_strings(i) || ', ' || v_numbers(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

or you can create an object type:
CREATE TYPE data_obj IS OBJECT( dummy VARCHAR2(1), lvl NUMBER );

and then use:
DECLARE
  TYPE data_list IS TABLE OF data_obj;
  v_data data_list;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select data_obj(dummy, level) from dual connect by level <= 5'
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_data;

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_data.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_data(i).dummy || ', ' || v_data(i).lvl);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Both of which output:
X, 1
X, 2
X, 3
X, 4
X, 5

fiddle

You cannot directly use Execute immediate for looping in a cursor.
Instead, you need a "REF CURSOR":
DECLARE
    v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;  -- Declare a cursor variable
    rec   VARCHAR2(100);  -- Variable to hold the result of each row
BEGIN
    -- Open the cursor for the dynamic SQL query
    OPEN v_cur FOR 'SELECT dummy FROM dual';
    
    -- Fetch each row from the cursor
    LOOP
        FETCH v_cur INTO rec;  -- Fetch each row into 'rec'
        EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;  -- Exit the loop when no more rows
        --DO STUFF YOU NEED FOR EACH INDEX HERE
    END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE v_cur;  -- Close the cursor
END;


This doesn't work with multiple columns like SELECT 1, 2 FROM dual, right?

You can create the cursor with the id or unique key that when it loops, you can get the whole row by the unique id. Why do you need multiple columns though?
